# Compose two images in shellscript

Tags: shell, ubuntu, imagemagick

Hello Friends I am trying to compose two images in imagemagick shell script commane but getting some problem here.
My problem is this I have two folders. In first folder let call it A and the second one let call it as B. In both A and B folder there are some images with the same name just like in folder A there is an image named as 'a' and the same named folder is in B folder. Now I want to make them compose with this command

```
composite -compose over -geometry +125+25 -background white
a.png a.png output.png
```

In this command image of A folder named as 'a.png' will be compose with B folders 'b.png' and the output will be 'output.png'.Now I can do this manually just one by one by running the command in terminal. I want the shell script of this one by which I can make compose large number of files.Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you meant

```
composite -compose over -geometry +125+25 -background white A/a.png B/a.png output.png
```

and that you want to put your results into a directory named `out`.

in the following:

```
for afile in A/* ; do
  base=$(basename "$afile")
  composite -compose over -geometry +125+25 -background white "A/$base" "B/$base" "out/$base"
done
```

The two basic features used here are [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) and the [basename](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basename) command that returns just the file name part of a path.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and +1 from me but it is showing some error like 'unable to open "B/$base". I think here only A is defined but B is not defined.So any idea behind that?

Comment: Works for me. Is your shell bash?